# Class setup failure handler for nosetests

Tags: python, nose

We're using nosetests and when the class setup method fails, the class tear down isn't called. This is problematic for us because

1. the class tear down shuts down a shared server. That means if it's not called then subsequent classes don't start properly
2. on setup failure the exception error message isn't actually useful---HttpConnectionError---we'd like to actually dump the server logs instead

We could wrap the class setup method in a try-catch block but as alluded to above, we actually have dozens of test classes---each with a different test setup---so a boilerplate approach is error prone.

Is there a way to add a class setup failure handler?

Comment: When the setup fails there's something wrong with it. It is not part of the actual assertion part of the test and shouldn't raise exceptions. So, fix your setup maybe by handling exceptions.  Also if one test fails the values of the other tests is reduced.

Comment: you are misundersting the question, the *class* setup fails to spin up a server, and i wish there was a `class setup error handler` that tells me why. And preferably defined in a parent class because not being DRY would make the tests unmaintainable @KlausD.